# Problemas para importar modulo pyodbc usando bottle

Tags: python, sql-server, bottle

Estoy trabajando en `windows` y usando `bottle` para conectarme a una base de datos de `SQL server`, para ello instale `pyodbc` con `pip install pyodbc`sin embargo cuando quiero cargar el programa siempre me sale el error

```
ImportError: No module named pyodbc
```

estoy usando la versión de `python 2.7.14` y revisando me aparece que el `pyodbc` esta instalada en la carpeta de python27 dentro de lib, leí que instalando  `Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 for python` solucionaba el problema, sin embargo sigue dándome ese error.

Comment: Efectivamente la instalación de Visual C++ 9.0 resuelve el problema porque `setup.py` intenta compilar algunas bibliotecas de C++ durante la instalación del complemento. Creo que Cygwin C++ también funcionará debido a los contenidos de `setup.py`.

Comment: @J.Rodríguez instale el visual y reinstale el pyodbc sin embargo sigue dandome el mismo resultado, probare con el Cygwin C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que coloque en el comentario no le funciona, pruebe hacer esto:

En tu proyecto en tu proyecto:

> 1- Presione <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> para abrir la configuración.
>
> 2- En la columna de la izquierda, selecciona Intérprete del proyecto
>   en la parte superior derecha hay una lista de binarios de `Python` que se encuentran en tu sistema, selecciona el correcto.
>
> 3- Eventualmente haga clic en el botón <kbd>+</kbd> para instalar módulos adicionales de `python`.
>
> 4- Validar.

[image: Imagen]

> Fuente SO: [ImportError: No module named 'bottle' - PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26069398/8933039)

---

**Si esto no funciona intente hacer lo siguiente:**

Configuración de las variables `PYTHONPATH` / `PYTHONHOME`

> 1- Haga clic derecho en el icono de la computadora en el menú de inicio.
>
> 2- Vaya a propiedades.
>
> 3- En la pestaña izquierda, vaya a Configuración avanzada del sistema.
>
> 4-  En la ventana que aparece, vaya a la pestaña Avanzado.
>
> 5-  Luego en la parte inferior haga clic en Variables de entorno.
>
> 6-  Haga clic en la lista de variables de usuario y comience a escribir en `Python`, y repita las variables del sistema, solo para asegurarse de que no tiene variables mal configuradas para `PYTHONPATH` o `PYTHONHOME`.
>
> 7- A continuación, agregue nuevas variables (lo hice en Sistema en lugar de Usuario, aunque también puede funcionar para el Usuario):
>
> `PYTHONPATH`, establecido en `C:\Python27\Lib.PYTHONHOME`,
>
> Establecido en `C:\Python27`.

Y también debe agregar `% PYTHONHOME%` a su variable de ruta para que esto funcione.

Por ejemplo, si instaló en `C:\Python27`, esto lo puede establecer por la linea de comandos:

```
set PYTHONHOME=c:\Python27
set PYTHONPATH=c:\Python27\Lib
set PATH=%PYTHONHOME%;%PATH%
```

Asegúrate de no tener un `'\'` final.

> Fuente SO : [Python (Windows) - ImportError: No module named site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5687052/8933039)

---

**Adicional a esto:**

Puede que haya tenido alguna versión anterior de `Python` instalada por ejemplo la versión: `Python2.5` y la ruta `PYTHONHOME` se estableció en `Python2.5`. Lo que debería hacer es renombrar a : `C:\Python27\` para la versión: `Python2.7.X` y quizás pueda resolver el problema.

---

**En cuanto a las Variables de Entorno:**

- Crear una nueva variable llamada `PythonPath`. En esta variable colocar algo como esto:  `C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk;C:\otras-carpetas-en-path`

[image]

Si no lo puede obtener asi, agregue:

> `C:\Python27;`

Mire más:

[image: imagen]

> `%PY_HOME%;%PY_HOME%\Lib;%PY_HOME%\DLLs;%PY_HOME%\Lib\lib-tk;`

[image: imagen]

Como control final, abra un símbolo del sistema e ingrese `Python`. Debería ver

```
>python [cualquier versión que estés usando]
```

> Si necesita cambiar de una versión a otra, solo necesita modificar la variable `PY_HOME` para que apunte al directorio correcto. Esto es un poco más fácil de administrar si necesita múltiples versiones de `Python` instaladas.

Fuente SO: [How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4855685/8933039)

Tal vez una de estas dos solucione te ayude. Saludos!

Comment: disculpa, cuando quiero añadir como en la imagen, me sale el error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main' , que puede estar pasando ahí?

Comment: @FernandoM.Goycochea me parece que esto tiene que ver con `__init__.py` (ahora llamada `__init__.py.bin`) significa que `Python` no entiende el kit de herramientas como un paquete.
 `__init__.py` esta en el directorio apropiado?

Comment: @FernandoM.Goycochea Vea si esto le sirve: [Python: Yet Another AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11568223/8933039)  o esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40113034/8933039

Comment: La verdad no sabría decirte ya que es la primera vez que intento añadir algo como en la imagen :(

Comment: @FernandoM.Goycochea bueno me temo que no se como mas poder ayudarte, probaste lo de las variables de entorno?

Comment: Si auque tengo una duda, lo coloque de esta forma C:\Python27\PYTHONPATH\C:\Python27\Lib.PYTHONHOME\% PYTHONHOME% en la parte de variable, esta bien asi? y la otra duda es si en la parte de variable de sistemas en path tambien lo coloco igual?

Comment: @FernandoM.Goycochea según tengo entendido solo debe incluir `PYTHONHOME` en `PATH`

Comment: ya no me sale el "importa pyodbc" en rojo lo que hice fue cambiar el interprete que estaba en 2.7 a 3.6 ahí si pude añadir los paquetes como me indicaste en la figura, muchas gracias aun así si pudieras explicarme mejor como añadir en las variables de entorno seria la ultima molestia

Comment: @FernandoM.Goycochea verifique la respuesta, la he editado agregando lo que solicita, Saludos!

Comment: muchas gracias.